# Create own warning in Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, resharper, warnings

I am trying to write some unit tests and I was wondering if there is a way to have a Resharper warning that will say something like "Hey, you need to run this test manually! Open somefile.txt to read how". Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with it yet, but the R# addins framework is supposed to be much easier to work in from R# 6 onwards...

Comment: Why not just mark the test with `Ignore` attribute and run it individually when needed? Some of my tests depend on a service which is not always available (and I have no control over it), so I marked them ignored and run them on demand in a separate session. `IgnoreReason` attribute can provide with more info to your teammates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [plugin](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/open_api.html) - Read through Jetbrain's documentation pages in the link.
You can also learn from the readable (and documented) example plugin - [Agent Johnson](http://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use structural search and save patterns in the catalog. http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/structural-search-and-replace/
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__SSR__Searching_for_Code_with_Pattern.html